# Mirror, Mirror, in the Code

Tags: code-golf, string

Two-dimensional programming languages often have mirror commands like `/` and `\` to redirect the instruction pointer on the grid:

```
>>>>\
    v
    v
<<<</
```

In this challenge, you're given an incoming direction and a mirror and you need to determine the outgoing direction.

### Rules

The incoming direction will be given as one of the characters `NESW` and the mirror will be given as either `/` or `\`. You may receive these in any order. You must use uppercase letters.

You may take input in any convenient format, including a two-character string, a string using some separator between the characters, a pair of characters in a list, or even a pair of singleton strings. If you do use a string with separator, the separator cannot use any of the characters `NWSE\/`.

Output should be a character from `NESW` or single-character string.

You may write a [program or a function](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2419) and use any of the our [standard methods](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447) of receiving input and providing output.

You may use any [programming language](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2028), but note that [these loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden by default.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid answer – measured in *bytes* – wins.

### Test Cases

There are only 8 possible inputs you need to handle, so there is no excuse for not testing your code on all of them:

```
N /   -->   W
N \   -->   E
E /   -->   S
E \   -->   N
S /   -->   E
S \   -->   W
W /   -->   N
W \   -->   S
```

Comment: In languages where backslashes must be escaped on input, are we allowed to assume the input will be "\\" where appropriate?

Comment: @JDL The actual *string* (or character) should contain a single ``\``. If your answer is a function submission that takes a string, then of course you'll need ``\\`` in the source code to call it correctly, but if you're reading your input from standard input, for instance, then it should be a single ``\``. In other words, if you call your language's respective string-length function on the input, the result should always be the same, regardless of whether the input contains `/` or ``\``.

Comment: Alright, I was expecting R to have problems when an unescaped "\" was entered via stdin, but `readline()` can handle it.

Comment: @JDL You probably need to _enter_ the string escaping (duplicating) that symbol, but the _resulting_ string will be "N\"

Answer (score 23):

## Python, <s>40</s> 38 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @MitchSchwartz `(ord(d)+ord(m))%8` -> `ord(d)+ord(m)&7`

```python
lambda d,m:' NESSWNW'[ord(d)+ord(m)&7]
```

plain lookup of answer in a list (AKA string) indexed by the smallest mod of the sum of ordinals that works.

Test cases are on [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/mPGH1A)

Comment: Dangit, I thought I was being super clever taking the ASCII values, summing them, `%8` them, and doing an index. Then I see you posted the same solution over an hour ago. Hah. Have a +1.

Answer (score 20):

## Python 2, 40 bytes

```
lambda c,m,k="NWES":k[k.find(c)^(m>k)+1]
```

Sp3000 saved one byte (`.index` → `.find`).

### Explanation

We want to map the directions like so:

```
       \
  N ⇄⇄⇄⇄⇄⇄⇄ E
  ⇅         ⇅
  ⇅         ⇅
/ ⇅         ⇅ /
  ⇅         ⇅
  ⇅         ⇅
  W ⇄⇄⇄⇄⇄⇄⇄ S
       \
```

We can assign the directions 2-bit codes, and view both flips as XOR-ing the first and second bits:

```
         xor 2
     0 0 ⇄⇄⇄⇄⇄ 1 0
      ⇅         ⇅
      ⇅         ⇅
xor 1 ⇅         ⇅ xor 1
      ⇅         ⇅
      ⇅         ⇅
     0 1 ⇄⇄⇄⇄⇄ 1 1
         xor 2
```

The mapping between bit strings and directions happens using the string `k`. Now we just need to map mirror characters `'/'` and `'\\'` to the values `1` and `2`. Since `'/' < '\\'`, we could naïvely use `(m>'/')+1` as a formula. But wait! Lexicographically,

```
'/' < 'NWES' < '\\'
```

and we have `'NWES'` nicely assigned to `k`! So we can use `(m>k)+1` instead.

Answer (score 12):

## CJam, 14 bytes

(@MartinEnder ported my [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92023/53748))

```
l1b" NESSWNW"=
```

How?

```
l1b" NESSWNW"= -
l              - read input
 1b            - cast characters as base 1 digits
   " NESSWNW"  - the string " NESSWNW"
             = - modulo index into the string
```

Tests are on [**aditsu**](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7B%0A%0Al1b%22%20NESSWNW%22%3D%0A%0AoNo%7D8%2A&input=N%5C%0AN%2F%0AE%5C%0AE%2F%0AS%5C%0AS%2F%0AW%5C%0AW%2F)

Answer (score 6):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>50</s> <s>41</s> <s>40</s> 37 bytes

```
d=>m=>(S="NWES")[S.search(d)^-~(m>S)]
```

*Saved 3 more bytes by using comparison, thanks to Lynn's answer*

#### Usage

```js
let f =
d=>m=>(S="NWES")[S.search(d)^-~(m>S)]

console.log(f("N")("/"));  //   -->   W
console.log(f("N")("\\")); //   -->   E
console.log(f("E")("/"));  //   -->   S
console.log(f("E")("\\")); //   -->   N
console.log(f("S")("/"));  //   -->   E
console.log(f("S")("\\")); //   -->   W
console.log(f("W")("/"));  //   -->   N
console.log(f("W")("\\")); //   -->   S
```

Comment: Clever use of ASCII comparisons to get your condition at the end playing your way...

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
'NWSE'jy&mjy+Eq-)
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=J05XU0UnankmbWp5K0VxLSk&input=Vwov) Or [verify the eight cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=ODoiCidOV1NFJ2p5Jm1qeStFcS0p&input=TgovCk4KXApFCi8KRQpcClMKLwpTClwKVwovClcKXA).

#### Explanation

```
'NWSE'    % Push this string
j         % Take first input, say 'W'. Stack contains: 'NWSE', 'W'
y         % Duplicate from below. Stack: 'NWSE', 'W', 'NWSE'
&m        % Index of membership. Stack: 'NWSE', 2
j         % Take second input, say '/'. Stack: 'NWSE', 2, '/'
y         % Duplicate from below. Stack: 'NWSE', 2, '/', 2
+         % Add (char '/' is converted to code point). Stack: 'NWSE', 2, 49 
Eq        % Multiply by 2, subtract 1. Stack: 'NWSE', 2, 97
-         % Subtract. Stack: 'NWSE', -95
)         % Apply -95 as (modular, 1-based) index into 'NWSE'. Stack: 'N'
          % Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 15 bytes

*Thanks to @Jakube and @Maltysen for -1 byte each*

```
@J"NWES"xxJQh>E
```

A program that takes input of two newline-separated quoted strings, first the direction and then the mirror, and prints the result.

This is a port of @Lynn's Python [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92014/55526).

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40J%22NWES%22xxJQh%3EE&input=%22E%22%0A%22%5C%5C%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22N%22%0A%22%2F%22%0A%22N%22%0A%22%5C%5C%22%0A%22E%22%0A%22%2F%22%0A%22E%22%0A%22%5C%5C%22%0A%22S%22%0A%22%2F%22%0A%22S%22%0A%22%5C%5C%22%0A%22W%22%0A%22%2F%22%0A%22W%22%0A%22%5C%5C%22&debug=0&input_size=2)

**How it works**

```
@J"NWES"xxJQh>E  Program. Inputs: Q, E
 J"NWES"         J="NWES". Yield J
         xJQ     J.index(Q)
             >E  E>Q, lexographically (implicit input fill)
            h    +1
        x        Bitwise XOR of the above two
@                Index into J with the above
                 Implicitly print
```

Comment: you can save another byte by replacing `<QE` with `>E`.

Answer (score 4):

## Java 7, <s>71</s> <s>70</s> 68 bytes

```
char c(int d,int m){return"NEWS".charAt("NEWS".indexOf(d)^-~(m%2));}
```

Too bad the `charAt` and `indexOf` takes up so much bytes..

**Ungolfed & all test cases:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/dhykEw)

```
class M{
  static char c(int d, int m) {
    return "NEWS".charAt("NEWS".indexOf(d) ^ -~(m%2));
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.print(c('N', '/') + " ");
    System.out.print(c('N', '\\') + " ");
    System.out.print(c('E', '/') + " ");
    System.out.print(c('E', '\\') + " ");
    System.out.print(c('S', '/') + " ");
    System.out.print(c('S', '\\') + " ");
    System.out.print(c('W', '/') + " ");
    System.out.print(c('W', '\\') + " ");
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
W E S N E W N S
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>14 13</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

(a port of my [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92023/53748))
-1 byte thanks to @MartinEnder (add a space to end of the string and remove need for modulo 8)
-1 byte thanks to @LuisMendo (take a single string argument rather than two)

```
OSị“NESSWNW
```

How?

```
OSị“NESSWNW  - takes a single argument "dm" (direction and mirror), in either order.
                   strings and lists are equivalent in Jelly
 O            - ordinal: [ord(d),ord(m)]
  S           - sum: ord(d)+ord(m)
    “NESSWNW  - string: "NESSWNW "
   ị          - fetch modulo index (the string is 8 long and 1-based)
```

Test it on [**TryItOnline**](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=T1Phu4vigJxORVNTV05XIA&input=&args=Ik4vIg)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
‘€Ã‘DIkI'/kÌ^è

‘€Ã‘             # from string "NEWS"
             è   # get element at index
    DIk          # index of 1st input in string "NEWS"
            ^    # XOR
       I'/k      # index of 2nd input in string "/"
           Ì     # +2
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCY4oKsw4PigJhESWtJJy9rw4xew6g&input=Tgov)

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>63</s> <s>61</s> 59 bytes

```py
lambda d,m,x='NESW'*2:x[x.find(d)+2*(m=='/\\'[d in'NS'])-1]
```

Pretty simple. Can definitely be golfed more. Decides whether to add 1 or -1 to the input's index in `'NESW'`.

This is a lambda expression; to use it, prefix it with `f=`.

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/jIBN2i)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>62</s> <s>58</s> 56 bytes

```
(d,m)->"SEWN".charAt("NWES".indexOf(d)^m.indexOf(47)+2);
```

## Ungolfed test program

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

public class Mirror {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BiFunction<String, String, Character> function = (d,m)->"SEWN".charAt("NWES".indexOf(d)^m.indexOf(47)+2);

    System.out.println(function.apply("N", "/")); //W
    System.out.println(function.apply("N", "\\")); //E
    System.out.println(function.apply("W", "/")); //N
    System.out.println(function.apply("W", "\\")); //S
    System.out.println(function.apply("E", "/")); //S
    System.out.println(function.apply("E", "\\")); //N
    System.out.println(function.apply("S", "/")); //E
    System.out.println(function.apply("S", "\\")); //W
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell v2+, 34 bytes

```
param($a,$b)"xNESSWNW"[(+$a+$b)%8]
```

Takes input as two explicit `char`s, outputs a `char`.

This works as follows: If we sort the output, we want `S` `/` to somehow equal the same as `N` `\`, `W` `/` to equal `E` `\`, etc. Or, at least, produce numbers that are "close enough" yet still distinct. If we look at the ASCII values, we get a table like the below:

```
In1   In2       Res.    Sum
S 83  / 47  --> E 69 -> 130
N 78  \ 92  --> E 69 -> 170
W 87  / 47  --> N 78 -> 134
E 69  \ 92  --> N 78 -> 161
W 87  \ 92  --> S 83 -> 179
E 69  / 47  --> S 83 -> 116
N 78  / 47  --> W 87 -> 125
S 83  \ 92  --> W 87 -> 175
```

Running a quick brute-forcer on the summations column (derived from summing the ASCII code points of the inputs) shows that if we take the sums modulo `8`, we get the following `2 2 | 6 1 | 3 4 | 5 7`. That's evidenced in the string `"xNESSWNW"`, as `E` is at index `2`, `N` is at `6` and `1`, and so on.

So, we just need to sum the inputs (implicitly casting from `char` to `int32` along the way), take that `%8`, and use that to index into our string.

#### Test Cases

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> ('N','/'),('N','\'),('E','/'),('E','\'),('S','/'),('S','\'),('W','/'),('W','\')|%{"$($_[0]) $($_[1]) --> "+(.\mirror-mirror-in-the-code.ps1 ([char]$_[0]) ([char]$_[1]))}
N / --> W
N \ --> E
E / --> S
E \ --> N
S / --> E
S \ --> W
W / --> N
W \ --> S
```

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 111 bytes

```
:goto %1
:W/
:E\
@echo N
@exit/b
:S/
:N\
@echo E
@exit/b
:E/
:W\
@echo S
@exit/b
:N/
:S\
@echo W
```

Accepts e.g. `W/` as a two-character string command line parameter. The `\` and `/` make looping awkward; it would have taken 124 bytes.

Comment: Idk, I count 96 bytes. Did you strip `\r` from it?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien I write my Batch files using Notepad, so, no.

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 30 bytes

Used the same order of arguments as Jonathan Allan.

Takes the input as two-character string `'W\'`.

```
@(x)['NESSWNW'](mod(sum(x),8))
```

Try it [online](https://ideone.com/zzyxeb).

Comment: Nice! You may want to port to MATL: `'NESSWNW 'is)` (see [all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=ODoiCidORVNTV05XICdpcykKRA&input=J04vJwonTlwnCidFLycKJ0VcJwonUy8nCidTXCcKJ1cvJwonV1wn)). `i` is `input`, `s` is `sum`, and `)` is indexing, which is modular. I added a space in the string so that the modulo is 8

Comment: Thanks :) I feel it's cheating if I add that as a separate answer, since I haven't written it myself. I can add it to this answer though if you don't want to answer it yourself :)

Comment: I understand, I would probably do the same :-) I don't want to modify my answer, as it's a totally different approach I didn't come up with. Not sure it adding it to your answer makes sense, though, as it would be two different languages in the answer

Comment: It would be my first MATL answer though :P I see it's longer than your MATL answer, so I don't think I'll add it...

Answer (score 2):

## C, <strike>44,</strike> <strike>35,</strike> 34 bytes

```
f(a,b){return"NWES"[a&a/2&3^b&3];}
```

It requires two characters as two variables. It takes both lower and upper case. It uses a lot of bit manipulation. The fragment `a&a/2` results in a value that has unique values for the lower two bits, `&3` cuts off all higher bits. This used as an index into the string "NWES" for the `\` mirror. Luckily, the lower two bits of the ASCII characters `\` and `/` are 00 and 11 respectively, which is perfect to XOR with the aforementioned index to get the correct direction for the `/` mirror.

Comment: Nice! You missed an obvious -1 byte, though: `return"NWES"[...]` (omit the space).

Comment: Thanks Tim, it hadn't occured to me that that would be valid C :)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 17 bytes

```
r"SWEN"_e!r'/#=er
```

Input is space-separated.

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=ewoKciJTV0VOIl9lIXInLyM9ZXIKCm59OCo&input=TiBcCk4gLwpFIFwKRSAvClMgXApTIC8KVyBcClcgLw) (As a linefeed-separated test suite.)

This is the solution I found before posting the challenge. Not as short as Jonathan's cyclic indexing, but I thought this approach is quite interesting (and novel).

#### Explanation

The goal is use transliteration (i.e. using a character-to-character mapping) to replace the input character with the output character. To do this, we need to select the correct map based on whether the mirror is `/` or `\`. We'll map from the `SWEN` list to another one which we'll select conditionally. If the input list is `SWEN`, the two output maps need to be the following:

```
in  SWEN
/   ENSW
\   WSNE
```

Note that these are in sorted and reverse-sorted order (which is why we chose the seemingly random `SWEN` order as the input set). We could generate these by sorting the input list and the reversing the result if the input has `\`, but there's a better way:

```
r       e# Read incoming direction.
"SWEN"  e# Push input list for transliteration.
_e!     e# Duplicate and get all permutations. The way, `e!` is implemented, it
        e# always gives the permutations in sort order, regardless of the order
        e# of the input set. Specifically that means that "ENSW" will be first
        e# and "WSNE" will be last in this list.
r       e# Read the mirror.
'/#     e# Find the index of / in this string. If the mirror is '/', then this
        e# gives 0. Otherwise, this gives -1, indicating that '/' was not found.
=       e# Select the corresponding permutation. Indexing is zero-based and
        e# cyclic so that 0 (input '/') gives the first permutation "ENSW" and
        e# -1 (input '\') gives the last permutation "WSNE".
er      e# Perform the transliteration on the incoming direction.
        e# Printing is implicit.
```

Answer (score 1):

## SED <strike>48</strike> (42 + 1 for -r) 43

Saved 5 thanks to Martin Ender♦

```
s,N/|S\\,W,;s,E/|W\\,S,;s,N.|S/,E,;s,..,N,
```

Takes input as a two character string.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 98 bytes

```
If[#2=="/",{"S",,,,,,,,,"W",,,,,"E",,,,"N"},{"N",,,,,,,,,"E",,,,,"W",,,,"S"}][[LetterNumber@#-4]]&
```

Anonymous function. Takes two strings as input and returns a string as output.

Answer (score 0):

### C, 81 bytes

```
f(char*a){return a!="N/"&a!="S\\"?a!="N\\"&a!="S/"?a!="W\\"&a!="E/"?78:83:69:87;}
```

#### Usage

```
main()
{
    printf("N/ \t %c\n",f("N/"));
    printf("N\\\t %c\n",f("N\\"));
    printf("E/ \t %c\n",f("E/"));
    printf("E\\\t %c\n",f("E\\"));
    printf("S/ \t %c\n",f("S/"));
    printf("S\\\t %c\n",f("S\\"));
    printf("W/ \t %c\n",f("W/"));
    printf("W\\\t %c\n",f("W\\"));
}
```

**Output:**

```
N/      : W  
N\      : E  
E/      : S  
E\      : N  
S/      : E  
S\      : W  
W/      : N  
W\      : S
```

Comment: Works only on hardcoded values since uses pointer comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 13 bytes

```
@."EW¹0`Y"sCM
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40.%22EW%C2%B90%60Y%22sCM&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22N%2F%22%0A%22N%5C%5C%22%0A%22E%2F%22%0A%22E%5C%5C%22%0A%22S%2F%22%0A%22S%5C%5C%22%0A%22W%2F%22%0A%22W%5C%5C%22&debug=0)

Sum the code points, modular index, compressed string.

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 40 bytes

Hardcodes the inputs. Boring, but the shortest way.

```
sub("NEWS",1+int(inString("E/W\N\S/N/S\E\W/",Ans)/4),1
```